# Use Inten ACTION_DIAL with ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-intent, android-arrayadapter

I use Inten ACTION_DIAL With arrayAdapter

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + ****** ));
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
```

How Can I connect ***** with variable of tel.num in ArrayList
most of codes in web write number in intent code but I need varible

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srmSJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAY1l.png)

Answer (score 0):

I just checkout the screenshot you attached, I guess I understood what you mean. Change your variable name "Mobile" to something else. Lets say I changed it to "mob", I would achieve what you want like this...

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l){

            Mobile mobile = mob.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + mobile.getMobileNum()));
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
```

Moreover, the `mobile.getMobileNum()` is the mobile number getter in your model/pojo class.

Comment: No I need to replace **** with variable or code to connect with the number show in ArrayAdapter

Comment: @Mohamed Adel I have edited my code. Lemme know if you still need help.

Comment: Sorry but I get this error, I edit and add new pic with the error in the post

Comment: Change `ArrayList<Mobile> Mobiles = new ArrayList<Mobile>();` to `final ArrayList<Mobile> mob = new ArrayList<Mobile>();`. Also post your `Mobile.java` class, lemme see what's there.